InvalidParameterValue: Value (arn:aws:iam::acc_no:instance-profile/ip_name) for iamInstanceProfile.arn is invalid. Invalid IAM Instance Profile ARN
I'm getting this error when I'm trying to create ec2 instance and pass an instance profile with an associated role. I'm doing this from a Lambda function use node 18.x
code for the main ec2 part
async function createEC2(nanoId) {
  const ec2 = new EC2Client({});
  const iam = new IAMClient({});
  try {
    
    const ipname = makeid(10);
    
    await createInstanceProfileIfNotExists(iam, ipname);

    const addRoleToInstanceProfileParams = {
      InstanceProfileName: ipname,
      RoleName: "Ec2adminRole"
    };
    await iam.send(
      new AddRoleToInstanceProfileCommand(addRoleToInstanceProfileParams)
    );
    
    const iparn = await getInstanceProfileArn(iam, ipname);
    
    console.log(iparn);
    
    console.log("Role added to instance profile successfully.");
    const instanceParams = {
      ImageId: "ami-0c101f26f147fa7fd",
      InstanceType: "t2.micro",
      MinCount: 1,
      MaxCount: 1,
      IamInstanceProfile: {
        Arn: iparn,
      },
      UserData: Buffer.from(
        `#!/bin/bash
        sudo yum install nodejs npm -y > test1.txt
        aws s3 cp ./test1.txt s3://runscriptfilebucketforfovus/test1.txt
        export NANO_ID="${nanoId}" 
        echo $NANO_ID> test2.txt
        aws s3 cp ./test2.txt s3://runscriptfilebucketforfovus/test2.txt
        aws s3 cp s3://runscriptfilebucketforfovus/Script.js . > test3.txt
        aws s3 cp ./test3.txt s3://runscriptfilebucketforfovus/test3.txt
        npm install @aws-sdk/client-dynamodb @aws-sdk/client-s3 > test4.txt 
        aws s3 cp ./test4.txt s3://runscriptfilebucketforfovus/test4.txt
        node Script.js > text5.txt
        aws s3 cp ./test5.txt s3://runscriptfilebucketforfovus/test5.txt
    `).toString("base64")
    };
    const data = await ec2.send(new RunInstancesCommand(instanceParams));
.
.
.
//rest of the code 

Get Instance function
async function getInstanceProfileArn(iam, instanceProfileName) {
  try {
    const params = {
      InstanceProfileName: instanceProfileName
    };
    const data = await iam.send(new GetInstanceProfileCommand(params));
    console.log(data);
    return data.InstanceProfile.Arn;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error arn:', error);
    throw error;
  }
}

Create Instance Profile
async function createInstanceProfileIfNotExists(iam, instanceProfileName) {
  try {
    const listInstanceProfilesResponse = await iam.send(new ListInstanceProfilesCommand({}));

    const existingInstanceProfiles = listInstanceProfilesResponse.InstanceProfiles;

    const instanceProfileExists = existingInstanceProfiles.some(profile => profile.InstanceProfileName === instanceProfileName);

    if (!instanceProfileExists) {
      console.log(`Instance profile ${instanceProfileName} does not exist. Creating...`);
      const createInstanceProfileParams = {
        InstanceProfileName: instanceProfileName
      };
      const createInstanceProfileResponse = await iam.send(new CreateInstanceProfileCommand(createInstanceProfileParams));
      console.log("Instance profile created successfully:", createInstanceProfileResponse.InstanceProfile.InstanceProfileName);
    } else {
      console.log(`Instance profile ${instanceProfileName} already exists.`);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error creating or listing instance profiles:", error);
    throw error;
  }
}

The Role Ec2adminRole has a administratorAccess(Just for testing).
For
const data = await ec2.send(new RunInstancesCommand(instanceParams));

im getting
The error that i'm geeting
Please help me in understanding what i'm missing.
I have tried assigning name and arn ,each and both together
